# How to solve a mathematics operation

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this code but on my form, when I put value on "MontantPaye" the operation:
`const result = montantTotalCom - montantPaye;` gave me `(- montantPaye)` as result on "*ResteaPayer*" box

```
<script>
   
    function verifierMontant(value) 
    {
        const montantTotalCom = parseFloat(document.getElementById('MontantTotalCom').value);
        const montantPayeInput = document.getElementById('MontantPaye');
        const montantPaye = parseFloat(montantPayeInput.value);
        
        if (isNaN(montantPaye)) 
        {               
            montantPayeInput.value = '';
            montantPayeInput.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            montantPayeInput.focus();
        } 
        else if (montantTotalCom === '' || montantPaye <= montantTotalCom) 
        {          
            montantPayeInput.style.backgroundColor = '';
            const result = montantTotalCom - montantPaye;              
            document.getElementById('ResteaPayer').value = result;
        } 
        else 
        {              
            montantPayeInput.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            montantPayeInput.focus();
            document.getElementById('ResteaPayer').value = '';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There is not enough information to identify what the problem is. Please [edit] to add a [mcve]. If I fill in the missing details [there is no issue](https://jsbin.com/wehokopizi/1/edit?html,js,output). This whatever it is, must be related to code not seen here.

Comment: Please click [edit], then the button shaped like `[<>]` and add relevant HTML, CSS and script